# insert multiply records to a form, from JSON file using postman

Tags: priority-web-sdk

How can I insert multiply records to a form using postman?

my data is in JSON file
and I use POST request:

"https://jrpostest.domjr.local/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/jrdf/SUPPLIERS"

getting the error below

[image]

Comment: please include your image into your question, because the link could become invalid in the futur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use batch request in order to insert multiple records into a parent form with
one server call.

```
POST
https://jrpostest.domjr.local/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/jrdf/$batch

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "SUPPLIERS",         
            "body": {
                "SUPNAME": "33445566",
                "SUPDES": "33445566"                                
            }
        },
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "SUPPLIERS",         
            "body": {
                "SUPNAME": "33445577",
                "SUPDES": "33445577"                                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that batch requests are available from Priority version 19.1.
In previous versions you will need to send two POST requests to the SUPPLIERS endpoint.